# Edge Animate: Set image src within a symbol - How?

Tags: image, jquery-animate, src, symbols, adobe-edge

I have created a symbol in Edge Animate, which contains a rectangle as view area and an image and text as contents of that view area. I want to set text and image src before I start the animation of the symbol. So when a certain area is clicked, I can set "Text" with

```
var thing = sym.getSymbol("mySymbol");
thing.$("Text").html("I can set some text here to change the content of Text.");
```

Question now is, how I can set the image source for the item "Image" within that symbol. I have looked into the files Edge Animate creates, and the text as shown above is in a field called "text", while the name of the image is contained with other information in a field called "fill". I don't have a clue how to set the image source. Any pointers?

Thanks in advance

M.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solid solution, which I've been working out over the past few hours.

---

**General**

The first step is to get a reference to the element, for example, if the element is named "MyTextBox", you would address it like this:

```
$(sym.lookupSelector("MyTextBox"));
```

---

**Dynamically Changing Text**

To do this, you can set the HTML property for the referenced element:

```
$(sym.lookupSelector("MyTextBox")).html("Hello World");
```

---

**Dynamically Changing Images**

Images are implemented by using the background-image CSS property of a DIV.  If you had an image element named MyImageBox, the syntax would be:

```
$(sym.lookupSelector("MyImageBox")).css('background-image', [image]);
```

There's a second part, which is getting the [image] reference correct.

- If it's in the default Edge images directory, use the relative URL:
  `images/MyNewImage.png`
- Use standard syntax for CSS background-image:
  `url(images/MyNewImage.png)`

Answer (score 0):

one approach might be to append an img tag and define its source.

for example:

```
$('<img src="mypic.png">').appendTo($('Text'));
```

replace "`mypic.png`" with the path for the image you want to use.

hope this helps.